# Using Multiple Fields in DECODE Expression in PS Query

Tags: sql, expression, peoplesoft

I'm trying to derive a value for a field for PS query results and the value is based on multiple table fields, not just one. Here's an example of the code I got to work:

```
DECODE(A.ACAD_PLAN,'BA 000','ASSIGN',Q.ACAD_PLAN,NULL,'DO NOT ASSIGN').
```

There are 3 options for my data:

1. `ACAD_PLAN = 'BA 000'` (I want it to assign "ASSIGN")
2. `ACAD_GROUP = 'SAM' and ACAD_PLAN is NULL` (assign "DO NOT ASSIGN")
3. `ACAD_GROUP = 'SAM' and ACAD_PLAN = 'SAM xxx'` *there could be multiple plan codes after SAM*, (assign `"ASSIGN WITH CAUTION"`)

The code above works to insert the `'ASSIGN'` and `'DO NOT ASSIGN'`, but this leaves #3 out. In order to keep this as simple as possible, I wanted to simply say: `ELSE 'ASSIGN WITH CAUTION'`. I tried writing it as:

```
DECODE(A.ACAD_PLAN,'BA 000','ASSIGN',Q.ACAD_PLAN,NULL,'DO NOT ASSIGN','ASSIGN WITH CAUTION')
```

My results are that only the `"ASSIGN"` gets populated and everything else is blank.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest for this would be to use a case statement.  You don't mention what your DB is but the syntax should be something similar to this.

```
select
Case 
    when ACAD_PLAN = 'BA 000' then 'ASSIGN'
    when ACAD_GROUP = 'SAM' and ACAD_PLAN is NULL then 'DO NOT ASSIGN'
    when ACAD_GROUP = 'SAM' and ACAD_PLAN = 'SAM xxx' then 'ASSIGN WITH CAUTION'
End
From ....
```